# how to make a dive push the content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple javascript that allow me to show/hide a div when the user click on a link, my problem with this is that the revealed div doesnt push down the container and the content below will "overflow" the column it is inside; so here is an example of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head id="Head1">
<title> 
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/foundation/css/foundation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/foundation/css/app.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/foundation/css/normalize.css" />
<link href="../App_Themes/default/Styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body style="background-color:#444649;">

    <div class="row" style="background-color:#D3D3D3;" data-equalizer>

        <form method="post" action="editor.aspx" id="frmServer" data-abide="">
            <div class="aspNetHidden">
            <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNTU0MTgyNDEwZGTdVjZUY5odoklB7xnAjVCPgPQ3lOfSJRpFogEKCgduiw==" />
            </div>

            <div class="aspNetHidden">

                <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="67C3659D" />
                <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAAP+8UmyYUk0AeVktlUECN0Go74pC+Y21+wE01Qq7CRmM9siBWxnYUgYbB45JL+mIkohgG+sbNy0e/PhzeTe4OpBJA8LnM3mlHw6DURiC8g6xg==" />
            </div> 

             <!-- IMPORTANT: padding-bottom:40rem; is currently in use only to exploit the problem, however it is not supposed to be here -->
            <div class="small-12 columns" style="padding-bottom:40rem;background-color:#ffffff;" data-equalizer-watch>                
                <a class="button tiny" href="#" onclick="Toggle('ib_intro')">INTRODUZIONE</a>&nbsp;
                <a class="button tiny" href="#" onclick="Toggle('ib_using')">USING</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a class="button tiny" href="#" onclick="Toggle('ib_filter')">FILTER</a>&nbsp;
                <a class="button tiny" href="#" onclick="Toggle('ib_cycle')">CYCLE</a>&nbsp;
                <a class="button tiny" href="#" onclick="Toggle('ib_period')">PERIOD</a>&nbsp;
                <a class="button tiny" href="#" onclick="Toggle('ib_twin')">TWIN</a>&nbsp;
                <a class="button tiny" href="#" onclick="Toggle('ib_output')">OUTPUT</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a class="button tiny" href="#" onclick="Toggle('ib_esempi')">ESEMPI</a>&nbsp;

                <div id="ib_intro" class="info_box" style="display:none;">
                    <!-- content -->
                </div>   

                <div id="ib_using" class="info_box" style="display:none;">
                    <!-- content -->
                </div>   

                <div id="ib_filter" class="info_box" style="display:none;">
                    <!-- content -->
                </div>   

                <div id="ib_cycle" class="info_box" style="display:none;">
                    <!-- content -->
                </div>   

                <div id="ib_period" class="info_box" style="display:none;">
                    <!-- content -->
                </div>   

                <div id="ib_twin" class="info_box" style="display:none;">
                    <!-- content -->
                </div>   

                <div id="ib_output" class="info_box" style="display:none;">
                    <!-- content -->
                </div>   

                <div id="ib_esempi" class="info_box" style="display:none;">
                    <!-- content -->
                </div>   

                <div>
                    <!-- content -->
                </div>

            </div>       

        </form>   
    </div>    

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/foundation/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/foundation/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.abide.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.equalizer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.tooltip.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Toggle(div_id){
            if (document.getElementById(div_id).style.display == "block") {
                document.getElementById(div_id).style.display = "none";
            } else {
                document.getElementById(div_id).style.display = "block";
            }            
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).foundation();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**edit**: added full page code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vvx8uham/ - everything should be ok, issue is somewhere else

Comment: Could you provide the CSS for this part of the page?

Comment: @BrianRay I'm using Foundation 5 and the part above is the content of a MasterPage, the whole thing is inside a row element

Comment: @elnath78 If you want people to help you, you need to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @BrianRay its reasonable but I cannot post the whole foundation 5 with css and js, should I find the solution I'll update this question

Comment: @elnath78 I made a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/pacezoneho/edit?html,css,js,output) of the code you provided and it works just fine. I even wrapped the HTML in a div with the class of "row".

Comment: @BrianRay posted the whole page code and rephrased to better describe the problem, also you can see the js elements that the page is using and all its relevan css files/classes along with the whole page structure. The content markers consists of many divs each with 8/15 rows so the push is significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `$(document).foundation('equalizer');` at the bottom of the `Toggle()` function causes equalizer to recalculate the height of the div wrapping the buttons and info_box divs. Here is a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/cofeqolaxu/edit?html,css,js,output) that demonstrates this.